Micronaut Http Request Perform Errors on Encoding Body as Form-Data
I am trying to perform an HTTP request in form-data format to an external server using the Micronaut HTTP Client. However, when I make the request, the server returns an error as if the body is completely empty.
To test if my request was being sent correctly, I made a Node application to capture the request data, then I tested a validated request through postman calling this server, and the Java/Kotlin application also to this server. The content looks exactly the same, as you can see in the following.
Comparing Content of Application Request with Postman Request
If I change the URL in postman and make the same request, it will return success, as you can see in the following print:
Print of Postman Request
Print of a Empty Body Request on Postman
Log of Request
17:07:52.205 [Test worker] WARN  i.m.h.c.n.ssl.NettyClientSslBuilder - HTTP Client is configured to trust all certificates ('insecure-trust-all-certificates' is set to true). Trusting all certificates is not secure and should not be used in production.
17:07:53.692 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] DEBUG i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - Sending HTTP POST to https://ocd.com/api.php
17:07:53.695 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=36c78120781912df
17:07:53.695 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - transfer-encoding: chunked
17:07:53.695 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - host: ocd.com
17:07:53.902 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - HTTP Client Response Received (200 OK) for Request: POST https://ocd.com/api.php
17:07:53.902 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - date: Mon, 22 Jul 2024 20:07:53 GMT
17:07:53.902 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - server: Apache
17:07:53.902 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - vary: Accept-Encoding
17:07:53.903 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
17:07:53.903 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - x-xss-protection: 1;mode=block
17:07:53.903 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - x-content-type-options: nosniff
17:07:53.903 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
17:07:53.903 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - x-http2-stream-id: 3
17:07:53.904 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - content-length: 1320
17:07:53.904 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - Response Body
17:07:53.905 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - ----
17:07:53.905 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - {"code":400,"status":"Empty input array.\nTransfer-Encoding: chunked\nHost: ocd..com\nContent-Type: multipart\/form-data; boundary=36c78120781912df\n\n\n\n\nUSER: apache\nHOME: \/usr\/share\/httpd\nORACLE_HOME: \/usr\/lib\/oracle\/21\/client64\/lib\nSCRIPT_NAME: \/api.php\nREQUEST_URI: \/api.php\nQUERY_STRING: \nREQUEST_METHOD: POST\nSERVER_PROTOCOL: HTTP\/2.0\nGATEWAY_INTERFACE: CGI\/1.1\nREMOTE_PORT: 65321\nSCRIPT_FILENAME: \/app\/ocd\/prod\/www\/api.php\nSERVER_ADMIN: \nCONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT: \/app\/ocd\/prod\/www\nCONTEXT_PREFIX: \nREQUEST_SCHEME: https\nDOCUMENT_ROOT: \/app\/ocd\/prod\/www\nREMOTE_ADDR: 135.20.60.219\nSERVER_PORT: 443\nSERVER_ADDR: 135.122.129.127\nSERVER_NAME: \nSERVER_SOFTWARE: Apache\nSERVER_SIGNATURE: \nPATH: \/usr\/local\/sbin:\/usr\/local\/bin:\/usr\/sbin:\/usr\/bin\nHTTP_TRANSFER_ENCODING: chunked\nHTTP_HOST: ocd..com\nCONTENT_TYPE: multipart\/form-data; boundary=36c78120781912df\nproxy-nokeepalive: 1\nH2_STREAM_TAG: 000\nH2_STREAM_ID: \nH2_PUSHED_ON: \nH2_PUSHED: \nH2_PUSH: on\nH2PUSH: on\nHTTP2: on\nSSL_TLS_SNI: ocd..com\nHTTPS: on\nUNIQUE_ID: Zp68GQVLiVT8r4HwgmdXsgAA0hU\nFCGI_ROLE: RESPONDER\nPHP_SELF: \/api.php\nREQUEST_TIME_FLOAT: 1721678873.2902\nREQUEST_TIME: 1721678873\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n","time":"00.0016s","data":[]}
17:07:53.905 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - ----

Kotlin Code:
fun requestTickets() {

        val uri: URI = UriBuilder.of(configuration.url)
            .build()


        val bodyBuilder = MultipartBody.builder()
            .addPart("auth_user", configuration.authUser)
            .addPart("auth_key", configuration.authKey)
            .addPart("object", configuration.objects)
            .addPart("method", configuration.method)
            .addPart("queue_arr[]", "BRAZIL_SD")
            .addPart("event_id_last", "28218371")

        val body = bodyBuilder.build()

        val req = HttpRequest.POST(uri, body)
            //.contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE)
            .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
            //.contentType(MediaType.FORM)
            // .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE)

        val res = httpClient.toBlocking()
            .exchange(req, String::class.java)

    }

Note I've changed the contentType for all those options commented above.
Thank you

Changing MediaType


There's one difference between the Postman request and the request from your app that may cause the issue: The Postman request includes content-length header, while the MN httpclient includes header transfer-encoding: chunked. It seems like it's not possible to change this in config, and content-length header is removed when trying to add it in code. Maybe you should try with e.g. OkHttpClient to verify that missing content-length header is the issue, I've tested that it adds content length header for your code. BR
